# AWS ECS Fargate ALB cannot validate targetGroupArn

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb, aws-fargate

NOTE: This is about ELBv2 ALBs, not legacy load balancers, ELBv1, but my humble rep won't let me improve the tagging.

I'm attempting to create an AWS ECS Fargate service. I have created Application Load Balancers one for each container in the Task, and since create-service now supports multiple loadbalancers according to the docs - we should be all good, right? Since it's an ALB, I specify targetGroupArn rather than loadBalancerName, and since ECS has a service linked role created by default, AWSServiceRoleForECS I ought to be able to map target groups and go ahead and create the service, right? Not like it used to be when you had to create ecsServiceRole manually from what the internet tells me.

my command is

```
aws ecs create-service  --region $REGION --cluster $CLUSTER --service-name production-svc --task-definition $TASK_ARN --desired-count 2 --launch-type "FARGATE" --network-configuration "awsvpcConfiguration={subnets=[${SUBNET_1}, ${SUBNET_2}],securityGroups=[${SECURITYGROUP_ID}]}" --load-balancers=tgt-a,containerName=a,containerPort=5000,targetGroupArn=tgt-b,containerName=b,containerPort=6000
```

And the error I get is 
An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the CreateService operation: Unable to assume role and validate the specified targetGroupArn. Please verify that the ECS service role being passed has the proper permissions.

Now, looking though the internet it could either be that my load balancers don't exist (you'll have to trust me, they do - I supply target group ARNs, and those target groups exist as confirmed with aws elbv2 cli and are mapped to valid active application load balancers that all live in the same region as the cluster), or that the service mapped role (the one AWS created for me earlier) won't have enough rights to assume to verify the targetGroupArn.

Do I really have to add rights to the automatic ECS service mapped role? If so - *which* rights?

```
            "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer",
            "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets",
            "elasticloadbalancing:Describe*",
            "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer",
            "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets",
```

My Automatic role (that has AmazonECSServiceRolePolicy) already has all of those? Which ones are missing?

Comment: What about your own permissions? It seems to be that you are not able to `AssumeRole` to make the call, not the ECS service? Do you execute the ecs command by assuming a role?

Comment: Interesting. the CLI account I use has the AdministratorAccess policy, I would have thought that would be enough.

Comment: `AdministratorAccess` more then enough. I don't know why you are getting `AssumeRole` when calling `CreateService`.

Comment: Did you specify the full Target Group ARN? From the command, looks like you're specifying just the name and that could be the cause. If you're specifying the ARN and still seeing this, look at the cloudtrail entry to see if you can find more details? Error messages sometimes can be a little misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue, and can confirm what Ali says:

Turns out that if you are creating the service via CLI with `aws ecs create-service` you need the full arn for the loadbalancer.

The documentation confirms that:
https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecs/create-service.html

It's a bit confusing because in the CloudFormation template you can just use the "short" name. Also the error message is a bit misleading.

Hope this helps.